# I am creating a React native web view

Tags: react-native

**My file name is talesrunner23 and splash.png file is in ASSETS, but when you run it, it says it can't be found
<Image source={require('/talesrunner23/assets/splash.png/')}They say I'm wrong here
please help me  I'm a beginner, so I have to write down all the codes
please please**

**I don't know at all**

```
*import React, { useRef, useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
 BackHandler,
 Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const DELAY_BEFORE_WEBVIEW = 10; // <--- seconds before webview load
export default function App() {
  // ref
  const webView = useRef();
  // callbacks
  const handleBack = useCallback(() => {
   if (canGoBack && webView.current) {
      webView.current.goBack();
     return true;
    }
    return false;
   `enter code here`;
  }, [canGoBack]);

  // effects
  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBack);
   return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBack);
    };
  }, [handleBack]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
   }, 30 * DELAY_BEFORE_WEBVIEW);
 }, []);
  // states
  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
       ref={webView}
       source={{ uri: 'https://www.talesrunnerbestguild.co.kr/' }}
        style={styles.webView}
        onLoadProgress={(event) => setCanGoBack(event.nativeEvent.canGoBack)}
      />
      {isLoading && <CenterLoader />}
    </View>
  );
}
const CenterLoader = () => (
 <View style={styles.loaderContainer}> 
<Image source={require('/talesrunner23/assets/splash.png/')} 
  style={{height:100,width:100}}/>
 </View>
);
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1 },
  loaderContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor:'white' // <-- comment this to show webview while loading
  },
  webView:
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? { marginTop: 30, marginBottom: 40 }
      : { marginTop: 30 },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not want to require but import the Image source at the top. Here is a quick example I made in a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/image-example-c4irqo?file=/src/App.js

```
import Cat from "./cat.jpeg";

function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Image
          accessibilityLabel="Cat"
          source={Cat}
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={styles.logo}
        />
        <Text style={styles.title}>Image Example</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want to find a part to modify in my code

Comment: I want to keep the splash image coming out